# Format date in JQuery DatePick (Keith Wood version)

Tags: jquery, datepicker, format

I am pulling a date from datepicker(Keith wood version) and writing it to a div using

```
$(function() {
  var  today = $.datepick.today();
  $("#date").html( today);
});
```

The format appears as below:

```
Tue Feb 26 2013 12:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)
```

I have tried to reformat this several times to no avail!

I need the long format:

```
Tuesday 26th February 2013
```

Can anyone be of assistance as this is really holding me back on a project?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the documentation for formatting dates? http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html (click the Format tab)

Comment: @Zak Yeah I have indeed , been at it for two days now can't seem to get any of the formatting to apply. Thanks for the reply though ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in the `dateFormat` option when you call the `datepick()` method:

```
$("#your-datepicker-input").datepick({dateFormat: 'DD d MM yyyy'});
```

[Documentation](http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html)

Comment: I already have tried that, and it makes no difference $('#inlineDatepicker').datepick({onSelect: writeDate, dateFormat: 'DD d MM yyyy'});

Comment: Since you're already using jQuery, is there any drawback to using jQuery UI's datepicker: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/?

Comment: Looks like I may have to use the UI version @Zak, I had this one running great until i needed to get that function going. just gonna set me back a bit sorting out the css etc!